# How to create identity colum

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have requirement to insert data to data base where a primary key is there in the table .But it need not be an identity column.I want to create by my own.I have decorated my ID property with attribute "DatabaseGeneratedOption.None".`[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int TestID { get; set; }`My query is where i need to generate the id. Is it in controller ?
Or I have read abbout GUID. Do i need to define my id as GUID ? Which is the best way?  i am working on mvc 4 , entity framework code first approach `

Comment: You should generate your ID before save changes in your context. But with int you can have problem with duplicated keys, and better choice will be to use GUID. Why when you only need to set next int as ID you don't want to use auto generated key?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say you want an identity column and then you explicitly say that's not what you want. Perhaps more information about the problem you're trying to solve would help. What needs to be accomplished? Why can't you use a standard identity column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Query = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>("Select isnull(Max(" + FieldName + "),0) from " + TableName).ToList();

if (Query.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
    row = 1; else 
    row = Query.FirstOrDefault() + 1;
```

I am using this approach to generate a new key for that table,